# Excel VBA - Highlight cell if time is greater than 24 hours ago

Tags: vba, excel

I have a report that will generally be run everyday just after 7am, but occasionally could be run later during the day.  In col D are ticket update times/dates.  If the ticket was updated yesterday, then the cell should be left alone; if the ticket was not updated yesterday (IE, if today is the 3rd, and it has not been updated since X o'clock on the 1st) the cell should highlight.  Since the report will occasionally not be run until later in the day, I can't do a simple CurrentTime - 24 hours to figure this out.  I need the function to always look for the previous day and before 7am.

Without knowing exactly how to code this, I know it should be something like:

```
If ticketUpdateTime < currentDay at 0700 - 24
Then highlight (I know the code for this part already)
End If
```

Hopefully this makes sense

Comment: To clarify, my question, the time/date is formatted like such:
11/02/2017 07:25:04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
If DateDiff("h", CDate(ticketUpdateTime), CDate(Format(Now(), "mm/dd/yy")) + TimeSerial(7, 0, 0)) > 24 Then
    highlight
End If
```

In plain English:

If the time elapsed between `ticketUpdateTime` and today's date at 07:00AM is more than 24 hours, highlight

It's a bit out of scope for the original question, but here's usage example as well:

```
Sub CheckTimes(rng As String)
    Dim someRange As Range, someCell As Range
    Set someRange = Range(rng) ' Convert input string to an actual range object

    For Each someCell In someRange
        If DateDiff("h", CDate(someCell.Value), CDate(Format(Now(), "dd/mm/yy")) + TimeSerial(7, 0, 0)) > 24 Then
            Debug.Print "Highlight"
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

To call it, input `Call CheckTimes("D2:D100")` or whatever range you need

Mind that there's no error-checking/-handling or data validation here - you'll have to do that yourself. ;-)

Comment: Great, thank you.  To select the values in column D (that is the column with the dates), would using a Range.Select and then With Selection, with the code you provided inside that, be the best method?

Comment: I prefer `Set`-ing a `Range` object and working on that object directly. `Select` can be fickle and error-prone in some cases. What's even easier is making the code range-agnostic (so you can supply the desired range at runtime). I'll throw in a small example.

Comment: Appears to be an of issue.  All of the dates/times are yesterday except for the value in D2 which is 11/01/2017 10:47:02, and that value is not highlighting.

Call CheckTimes("D2:D" & lastRow)

Sub CheckTimes(rng As String)
    Dim someRange As Range, someCell As Range
    Set someRange = Range(rng) ' Convert input string to an actual range object

    For Each someCell In someRange
        If DateDiff("h", CDate(someCell.Value), CDate(Format(Now(), "dd/mm/yy")) + TimeSerial(7, 0, 0)) > 24 Then
            someCell.Interior.Color = 16750899
        End If
    Next someCell
End Sub

Comment: That looks horrible.  Just posted a new comment at the bottom with what it should actually look like.

Comment: Figured it out.  Had to swap the day and month in the format

Answer (score 0):

You may use dateserial(Year as integer, month as Integer, day as Integer) and TimeSerial(Hour as Integer, Minute as Integer, Second as Integer). I don't know how exactly you ticketUpdateTime looks like, so its hard to write expression. However, previous day 7 am would be:

```
dateserial(year(date-1), month(date-1), day(date-1)) & " " &timeserial(7, 0, 0)
```

Comment: Or slightly more concise: `VBA.DateValue(Now - 1) + VBA.TimeSerial(7, 0, 0)`

Comment: Yes, to clarify, it is formatted like: 11/02/2017 07:25:04

Comment: so, you can wrap Robin's code with Format(VBA.DateValue(Now - 1) + VBA.TimeSerial(7, 0, 0), "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss"). And compare.

Comment: Assuming the cell `ticketUpdateTime` holds a datetime value (and not a string that looks like a date), the formatting is completly irrelevant when comparing dates.

Comment: If values are imported from external application I wouldn't assume that.

Comment: @Marcin: In that case you are dealing with strings and comparing will not help you to tell if or if not to mark the cells. The string `"31/10/2017"` is larger than `"01/11/2017"`

Answer (score 0):

Appears to be an of issue. All of the dates/times are yesterday except for the value in D2 which is 11/01/2017 10:47:02, and that value is not highlighting.

```
Call CheckTimes("D2:D" & lastRow)

    Sub CheckTimes(rng As String)
    Dim someRange As Range, someCell As Range
    Set someRange = Range(rng) ' Convert input string to an actual range object

    For Each someCell In someRange
        If DateDiff("h", CDate(someCell.Value), CDate(Format(Now(), "dd/mm/yy")) + TimeSerial(7, 0, 0)) > 24 Then
            someCell.Interior.Color = 16750899
        End If
    Next someCell
End Sub
```